# Solaris 11 - Extend/Grow ZFS Pool

Tags: solaris, zfs

At present, we have a Solaris server which is using ZFS as storage for the zones. The storage is presented from a SAN via LUNs.

I have a zpool that is 500gb in size (provisioned from a 500gb LUN from the SAN). I want to make this zpool 1000gb in size.
How do I expand this zpool to a larger size? Do I first grow the LUN from the SAN, and then extend it in Solaris?

What commands do I use to grow a zpool? and can this be done online or will a reboot be required?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions

1. You can enlarge your lun on the SAN but it depend of your SAN fonctions
2. Add news luns to your pool (zpool add pool_name disk_c#d#t# )